# Extract number from delimited string, with varying formats

Tags: sql-server, join

I'm trying to join two tables, `OrderLines` and `Production`, from our ERP system, running SQL Server 2014. The way it works is, if a product is added to an order and there is nothing in stock for that product, a "Production Entry" (Bill of Materials, essentially) is generated automatically for Production.

The `GeneratedEntries` field in the `OrderLines` table captures that data, recording which Production Entry numbers were generated for that order line. The field *usually* is in the following format: It starts with `PD~`, then is followed by an entry number, with subsequent entry numbers delimited by another tilde `~`. So a standard value for this field, for an order line that caused 2 entry numbers to be generated, might look like this:
`PD~12345~67891`

The issue is, the formatting for that field is sometimes not consistent, in that there are sometimes trailing tildes, sometimes the `PD~` is repeated in middle of the string, other extra garbage characters, etc.

I don't know how to extract the entry numbers from `GeneratedEntries` to join the two tables, in a way that would work for all formatting possibilities. Is there any way to do this?

Sample tables below with relevant columns (OrderNumber and Product aren't really relevant, just there for context...)

```
OrderLines Table
+-------------+---------+----------------------+
| OrderNumber | Product |   GeneratedEntries   |
+-------------+---------+----------------------+
|           1 | A       | PD~10005             |
|           1 | B       | PD~10006~            |
|           1 | C       | PD~10007~10008~10009 |
|           2 | R       | PD~10010~~10011      |
|           2 | L       | ~PD~10012~~          |
|           2 | Z       | PD~10013 PD~10014    |
+-------------+---------+----------------------+


Production Table
+-----------------+
| ProductionEntry |
+-----------------+
|           10005 |
|           10006 |
|           10007 |
|           10008 |
|           10009 |
|           10010 |
|           10011 |
|           10012 |
|           10013 |
|           10014 |
+-----------------+
```

Comment: What's the primary key on the OrderLines table?

Comment: @MaxSzczurek The primary key is `OrderNumber`, which typically joins to a separate `Orders` table which contains all the main order header info. I didn't think that was pertinent to this question.

Comment: The OrderNumber is the primary key of the orders table - not the OrderLines table. You need to establish uniqueness per row. What is the primary key of the OrderLines table? I'm guessing it's some combination of OrderNumber and some other field, like a line #. It's absolutely relevant to your question.

Comment: Yes you're right, my bad. Primary keys of OrderLines are OrderNumber and LineItem (Line #, like you guessed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Virtually any parse/split function will do.  Here is an inline approach.

The only trick is that we replace any SPACE with a ~ and filter with a try_convert()

**Example**

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([OrderNumber] varchar(50),[Product] varchar(50),[GeneratedEntries] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 (1,'A','PD~10005')
,(1,'B','PD~10006~')
,(1,'C','PD~10007~10008~10009')
,(2,'R','PD~10010~~10011')
,(2,'L','~PD~10012~~')
,(2,'Z','PD~10013 PD~10014')

Select A.OrderNumber
      ,A.Product
      ,B.* 
 From @YourTable  A
 Cross Apply (
                Select RetSeq = Row_Number() over (Order By (Select null))
                      ,RetVal = LTrim(RTrim(B.i.value('(./text())[1]', 'varchar(max)')))
                From  (Select x = Cast('<x>' + replace(replace([GeneratedEntries],' ','~'),'~','</x><x>')+'</x>' as xml).query('.')) as A 
                Cross Apply x.nodes('x') AS B(i)
             ) B
 Where try_convert(int,B.RetVal) is not null
```

I kept the sequence `RetSeq` just in case it was important.

**Returns**

```
OrderNumber Product RetSeq  RetVal
1           A       2       10005
1           B       2       10006
1           C       2       10007
1           C       3       10008
1           C       4       10009
2           R       2       10010
2           R       4       10011
2           L       3       10012
2           Z       2       10013
2           Z       4       10014
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this appears to work perfectly. I don't know what it all means but will attempt to pick your query apart. Also I neglected to mention in my question, as @MaxSzczurek rightly pointed out, that the primary keys for `OrderLines` are `OrderNumber` and `LineItem`. So I just had to add `LineItem` to your query, and join on those two fields.

Comment: @wysiwyg happy it helped and we'll done on the join.